# Python homework not working - receving an error

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to write this code but I Receve the following error and I am not sure exactly why it is not printing out.

The assigment is to make sure that whenever we pull out for example Ace of Spades, Ace of Hearts, Ace of Diamonds and Ace of Clubs they are not to be in the [my_cards] section.

I tried the following code:

```
import random

standard_cards = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
my_cards = {"Hearts": standard_cards, "Diamonds": standard_cards, "Clubs": standard_cards, "Spades": standard_cards}
new_cards = list(my_cards)
picked_cards = []

for card in range(3):
    random.shuffle(my_cards)
    chosen_card_color = random.choice(my_cards)
    chosen_card = random.choice(chosen_card_color)
    my_cards.remove(chosen_card)
    picked_cards.append(chosen_card_color + " " + chosen_card)

print("User took these 3 cards:\r\n", picked_cards)
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
"C:\Python lectures\TestovProekt\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Python lectures/TestovProekt/Domashno.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python lectures\TestovProekt\Domashno.py", line 19, in <module>
    random.shuffle(my_cards)
  File "C:\Users\BOP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\random.py", line 362, in shuffle
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
KeyError: 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: `my_cards` is a dictionary, which has no inherent order; shuffling a dictionary doesn't make sense. You can only shuffle something that has a specific order, like a list. If you want to shuffle the lists that each dictionary key (aka the card suits) points to, then you have to specifically shuffle the value of each of your dictionary's keys. However you would need to make 4 copies of `standard_cards` and have those be the values in the dictionary, since otherwise you just have 4 references to the same list, meaning if you shuffle one, all the others will be shuffled the same way.

Comment: @RandomDavis well, `dict` objects do maintain insertion order. But more importnatly, `random.shuffle` assumes a mutable *sequence*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know that's the case with `OrderedDict` at least, but this is just a plain `dict`, which isn't guaranteed to keep insertion order in all implementations of Python.

Comment: @RandomDavis it is guaranteed on Python 3.7+

Comment: @RandomDavis thank you for the advice, could you please help me how to write that code, i'm very new to python and don't seem to understand very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mycards` is a dictionary, which you can't shuffle. As you want to choose a card color here, I think you intended to chose from `new_cards`, which does contain the 4 card colors. This also requires that you've to get the card itself with a dictionary key. Also, first shuffling and then choosing random appears me a bit useless, you can't concatenate strings and int and, as [Random Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6273251/random-davis) said, you should copy your standard_list. Otherwise, the cards will be removed from every color, and not only from the one you just chosen, meaning that you'll never get 2 the same card of a different type. 
The entire code should look something like this:

```py
import random

standard_cards = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
my_cards = {"Hearts": standard_cards.copy(), "Diamonds": standard_cards.copy(), "Clubs": standard_cards.copy(), "Spades": standard_cards}
#you can leave one of them uncopied, as it won't affect the other ones anymore now.
new_cards = list(my_cards)
picked_cards = []

for card in range(3):
    chosen_card_color = random.choice(new_cards)
    chosen_card = random.choice(my_cards[chosen_card_color])
    my_cards[chosen_card_color].remove(chosen_card)
    picked_cards.append(chosen_card_color + " " + str(chosen_card))

print("User took these 3 cards:\r\n", picked_cards)
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in The_spider's answer, there are a number of issues with your original code. Their answer addresses those issues, so I will propose a different solution using a `list` of card tuples:

```py
import random
import itertools


ranks = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"]
cards = list(itertools.product(ranks, suits))

deck = cards.copy()
random.shuffle(deck)

user_hand = [deck.pop() for _ in range(3)]
```

Output:

```py
[(3, 'Diamonds'), ('J', 'Spades'), (10, 'Clubs')]
```

From here, it'd be pretty straight-forward to use a dictionary to store "players", and deal new hands to all the players in the correct order (instead of 3 cards at once for each player which is not how poker hands are dealt).

Comment: didn't think about that. What if you use a set instead, then you don't have to shuffle it anymore?